# Can I learn Haml and Sass even if I don't know Ruby?

Tags: ruby, haml

I downloaded Haml from here: http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=2760. When I extract the zip there are a bunch of .rb files and the official web page talks about gems. I think this is some Ruby stuff.

Can I learn Haml and Sass even if I don't know Ruby?

If I have to, how do I install all this on Windows XP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Implementations
>
> The official implementation of Haml
>   has been built for Ruby with plugins
>   for Ruby on Rails and Merb, but the
>   Ruby implementation also functions
>   independently.
>
> There are also implementations in
>   other languages:
>
> ```
> * GHRML (Python)
> * LuaHaml (Lua)
> * MonoRail NHaml (ASP.NET)
> * NHaml (.NET)
> * Fammel (PHP)
> * pHAML (PHP)
> * phpHaml (PHP5)
> * haml-js (JavaScript)
> * Text::Haml (Perl)
> ```

Do you know any of those languages?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to know ruby as such since both projects are domain specific languages for writing html and css. I think knowing a bit of Ruby will help you in using both projects since you can leverage Ruby's capabilities in abstracting common things away in your code.

Regardless of whether you want to learn Ruby or not, you will have to install Ruby and the dependencies for Haml and Sass in order to be able to use them on Windows.

Finally, Ruby Gems is a package manager for Ruby, that is used to install and manage Ruby libraries on your system.

You can get Ruby from [here](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/) and Ruby Gems [here](http://rubyforge.org/projects/rubygems/).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you don't want to install Haml/Sass at all but want to try it out, you might want to play with:

http://rendera.heroku.com/

Comment: Nice, but it really should use a frame for output, like jsFiddle and JS Bin, because for example, this piece of code `body { color: red; }` makes the entire page's color red.

Comment: Also http://tinkerbin.heroku.com/ , which is similar but looks like it might be a little better designed.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn Haml and Sass just by reading the docs on their site, the only thing you need to know is HTML and CSS respectively. Haml official implementation is written in Ruby, and its the easiest way to use it with any web framework out there. Installing Ruby is pretty simple under Windows:

http://rubyinstaller.org/ <- Ruby installer for Windows.

To add on the implementations there is already one for Go!

https://github.com/realistschuckle/gohaml

So if you're into that you can just compile the executable and run the parser through the command line.
Problem with most implementations of Haml in other languages is the lack of filters for :markdown and such. There is where the Ruby implementation stays at the top for its simplicity and the ability to use ruby gems.

If you install Ruby for Windows then just in cmd:

```
gem install haml sass
```

I recommend you to start learning Ruby too, pretty simple with Sinatra so you can test everything you do in realtime.

```
gem install sinatra
```

Create a directory. Inside create a **views** and a **public** directory. Inside the **views** directory just put a *layout.haml* with **=yield** on it somewhere in your body, all your other files will be rendered there. Create an *index.haml* also in the **views** directory and a .rb file with any name at the root of that directory, there you're going to write on it.

```
require 'haml'

get '/' do
  haml :index
end
```

now just run *ruby myfile.rb* from the command line and you will have a server running you can look at the browser. You don't have to reload the server for changes in the haml files, just in the .rb
You can call any haml file and it will be rendered in the **=yield** part of your layout.

The **public** directory is where you can put images, js, css and such.

More info on http://www.sinatrarb.com/ I have found that sinatra is pretty simple to setup to have realtime Haml templates and views rendered, without having to compile them. Hope it helps.